# On what basis is mental illness considered the result of sin?

Tags: sin, mental-illness

I have heard some Christians say that mental illness is the result of sin. On what grounds, Biblical or otherwise, do they make this claim?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. Your question, though a good one, is not a good fit for this site as presently written. This site is about the beliefs of particular Christian denominations, and the biblical basis of those beliefs. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We can't tell you whether something is or isn't a sin, because different Christian denominations will have different views on this. But you could ask what particular denominations believe about this if you wish.

Comment: @JontheArchitect Please do _not_ answer questions in comments. Comments can explain why the question isn't a good fit or what to do to fix it, but throwing in a mini answer while your at it is not good for the system. See [this](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1601/30) for some background on a parallel issue and other meta posts about closed questions for why we don't answer them.

Comment: The question you asked was too broad for our site, because there are many opinions on mental illness within Christianity. But you were *very close* to a question we can address, so I edited your question to fit within our guidelines, by focusing on one particular viewpoint. You should consider asking a second question to address the counter-point "On what basis is mental illness not considered the result of sin?"

Comment: Ronnie, please confirm that Flimzy's edit still reflects a question that you'd like to have answered.  If so, this question can be reopened and answered.